# Meaning of concentric circles on the spectrogram

Tags: spectrogram

I've got this unusual spectrogram and I am really curious what these circles could mean. Has anyone ever seen anything like this? What could be the source of the signal?

[image: spectrogram]

Comment: Would it be possible to provide some more information about this? For example, a plot of the signal in the time domain, the package, function name and parameters you are passing to it and whether you built the spectrogram function? This has an "audio explanation" but its boring and unlikely and the pattern is suspiciously log and regular. Could be a bug in overlap-(add/save) or poor choice of parameters.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, i.e. what kind of signal could produce this spectrogram! First, I thought that the pattern is due to a 'bug' or improper usage. But while the circles are regular they are not regular enough... Do you mind to share your "audio explanation" or just give me some clue?

Comment: OK, straightforward answer from what is provided: If this is an audio signal, then it could have resulted from something that sounds like this https://freesound.org/people/Timbre/sounds/122950/ until the pause followed by its reversed version. But your case doesn't contain this much noise and seems to also have some echo added to it because faint "circles" appear shifted in time too. But without a bit more information it is impossible to provide any more meaningful help (i.e. whether this could be the result of bug or erroneous parameters).

Comment: It looks much like some Moiré pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Understanding [FFT Overlap Processing](http://materias.fi.uba.ar/6644/info/anespec/avanzado/real%20time/understanding%20FFT%20Overlap%20Processing.pdf), p. 10, it is suggested that uniform of constant windows, for certain hop patterns, with repeated pulses, could generate such artifacts.

[image: Spectrogram with Moiré]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to comment yet but could it be some kind of FM Synthesis?
Like Olli Niemitalo wrote, it looks like Moiré pattern. I found a [spectrogram](https://freesound.org/people/metamorphmuses/sounds/39370/) which looks a little bit similar:
[image]